# Does Reordering and Regrouping the functions in a Conditional Infinite Series (as described) terms change its Sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Consider any infinite conditional convergent series of the form: $Sum_0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) + g(n) + h(n) = C_0$. Here each 'term' consists of 3 separate functions $f(n), g(n), h(n)$. Now assume two oerations:

1. we reorder the functions in each 'term' as follows:  $Sum_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) + h(n) + f(n) = C_1$
2. we 're-bracket'/regroup the 'terms' and rewrite the new series as follows:  $Sum_2=f(1) + g(1) +\sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n) + f(n+1)+g(n+1) = C_2$

In each of the following case the $Sum$ does not change, thus: $Sum_0=Sum_1=Sum_2=C_0=C_1=C_2.$

**Query:** Now, if we both reorder the functions in the term as well as regroup them as follows: $Sum_3=g(1) + h(1) +\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) + g(n+1)+ h(n+1) = C_2$. Is it always true that the final sum will always remain unchanged i.e. $Sum_0=Sum_3=C_0=C_3$?

Comment: In your sums, the terms move only a bounded index away from where they began. This will not affect the sum of the series. It is only things like rearranging a1+b1+a2+b2 etc into say a1+a2+b1+a3+a4+b2 etc which can alter the sum.